# Django view render returns no html

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a really weird situation on my deployed project, code works fine on development. All other views are working except for ones in a certain app.

Looking in dev tools at the network tab, I get a 200 ok response, but just no html is sent.

And under the response tab it only says "Failed to load response data."

No error on the apache log, and I even did `Debug = True`, no error.

I also edited the view to just send an html file without any context, it doesn't work, 
however if I say

`return HttpResponse("hello")`

it works, this is what lead me to think it is an error in render.

Here's an example view

```
def user_login(request):
    return render(request, 'profiles/login.html', {})
```

Its clear the view is running, just not returning any html?

I'm using Django 1.6 and python 2.7

Comment: What does your `login.html` template look like?

Comment: Just normal html with a login form, however it does start with the `{% extends 'blah.html' %}` I thought that might be a source of the problem, but my other templates work fine with that

Comment: Okay, but there might be an error in `login.html`. If I can't see the code I can't help.

Comment: I tested to be sure and made a template like this 
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
Error
</body>
</html>` still same problem

Comment: i think you are using `post request` for rendering html .thats y `HttpResponse` works

Comment: wait no, the template above worked, so the error is in the html!

Comment: are you extending from a base html? you probably has a block empty